# Updating (redraw) basemap after panning through Navigation Toolbar Python

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap

I get some problems about basemap, where when I want to try panning or zooming map, then the map will be redrawed. Anyone who can give me some clues or methods in this case? Here is some code I included. thanks
(I'm sorry about my bad english)

main.py

```
 from toolbar import tool_bar
 from mapping import CanvasFrame

 class MainWindow(object):
    def __init__(self):
       ....
       self.create_basemap()

    def create_basemap(self):
       self.canvas = CanvasFrame()
       ....
       self.toolbar = tool_bar(self.canvas, self.window)
       self.vbox1 = gtk.VBox(False, 2)

       self.button1 = gtk.ToggleButton("zoom")
       self.button1.connect("toggled", self.get_zoom)

       self.button2 = gtk.ToggleButton("pan")
       self.button2.connect("toggled", self.get_pan)

       self.button3 = gtk.Button("restore")
       self.button3.connect("clicked", self.get_restore)

       self.vbox1.pack_start(self.button1)
       self.vbox1.pack_start(self.button2)
       self.vbox1.pack_start(self.button3)
       ....
    def get_zoom(self, button):
       if self.button1.get_active():
       self.button2.set_active(False)
       self.toolbar._zoom()
    def get_pan(self, button):
       if self.button2.get_active():
       self.button1.set_active(False)
       self.toolbar._pan()
    def get_restore(self, button):
       self.toolbar._restore()
    ....
```

mapping.py

```
 from matplotlib.figure import Figure
 from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
 from matplotlib.backends.backend_gtkagg import FigureCanvasGTKAgg as FigureCanvas
 ....
 class CanvasFrame(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self):
       self.figure = Figure(dpi=80)
       FigureCanvas.__init__(self, self.figure)
       self.ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
       self.plot_map()
    def plot_map(self):
       self.map = Basemap(projection = 'mill', resolution = 'i', llcrnrlon = 103.5,
                           llcrnrlat= -6.25,urcrnrlon = 107, urcrnrlat = -3.7, ax = self.ax)
       ....
```

toolbar.py

```
 from matplotlib.backends.backend_gtkagg import NavigationToolbar2GTKAgg
 class tool_bar(NavigationToolbar2GTKAgg):
    def __init__(self, canvas, window):
       super(NavigationToolbar2GTKAgg, self).__init__(canvas, window)
    def _zoom(self):
       self.zoom()
    def _pan(self):
       self.pan()
    def _restore(self):
       self.home()
```